# How can the index in this code snippet ever reach 2154? (gcc, embedded C, ARM Cortex M0)

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I'm writing a driver for a GSM modem running on an ARM Cortex M0. The only UART on the system is in use for talking to the modem, so the best I can do for logging the UART conversation with the modem is to build up a string in memory and watch it with GDB.

Here are my UART logging functions.

```
// Max number of characters user in the UART log, when in use.
#define GSM_MAX_UART_LOG_CHARS (2048)

static char m_gsm_uart_log[GSM_MAX_UART_LOG_CHARS] = "";
static uint16_t m_gsm_uart_log_index = 0;

// Write a character to the in-memory log of all UART messages.
static void gsm_uart_log_char(const char value)
{
    m_gsm_uart_log_index++;

    if (m_gsm_uart_log_index > GSM_MAX_UART_LOG_CHARS)
    {
        // Clear and restart log.
        memset(&m_gsm_uart_log, 0, GSM_MAX_UART_LOG_CHARS); // <-- Breakpoint here
        m_gsm_uart_log_index = 0;
    }

    m_gsm_uart_log[m_gsm_uart_log_index] = value;
}

// Write a string to the in-memory log of all UART messages.
static void gsm_uart_log_string(const char *value)
{
    uint16_t i = 0;
    char ch = value[i++];

    while (ch != '\0')
    {
        gsm_uart_log_char(ch);
        ch = value[i++];
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on the line shown above, the first time it's reached, m_gsm_uart_log_index is already well over 2048. I've seen 2154 and a bunch of other values between 2048 and 2200 or so.

How is this possible? There's no other code that touches m_gsm_uart_log_index anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow happening which could trample on `m_gsm_uart_log_index`.

The check for end of buffers should be:

```
if (m_gsm_uart_log_index >= GSM_MAX_UART_LOG_CHARS) {
...
}
```

As it stands, `m_gsm_uart_log_index` can reach 2048, and so writing `m_gsm_uart_log_index[2048]` is likely to be at the location where `m_gsm_uart_log_index` is stored.

Comment: How foolish of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to the buffer when `m_gsm_uart_log_index == GSM_MAX_UART_LOG_CHARS`, which means that you are overrunning the buffer by 1 character. This writes into the first byte of `m_gsm_uart_log_index` and corrupts it.

Change:

```
if (m_gsm_uart_log_index > GSM_MAX_UART_LOG_CHARS)
```

to:

```
if (m_gsm_uart_log_index >= GSM_MAX_UART_LOG_CHARS)
```